# observer event laravel access to mutators not working

Tags: laravel

hi **status_fa_text** created with mutators but use on observer return ""

model example

```
 public function getStatusFaTextAttribute()
{
    $html = '';

    if ($this->status == 'new') {
        $html = Lang::get('document status is',['status' => Lang::get('pending')]);
    }
    if ($this->status == 'accept') {
        Lang::get('document status is',['status' => Lang::get('confirmation')]);
    }
    if ($this->status == 'failed') {
        Lang::get('document status is',['status' => Lang::get('failed')]);
    }


    return $html;
}
```

observer example

```
     static::updated(function ($document) {
        Notification::send(User::find($document->user_id),
            new SendNotificationToUsers($title, Lang::get('your id was changed in the system', ['status' => $document->status_fa_text]),
                Lang::get('authentication'), url('panel/authentication/profile'), 'approve', $userEmail, Lang::get('certificate of identification'), $document->status_fa_text));
    });
```

Comment: You are missing the $html variable before the Lang::get in the last two if statements

Comment: Missing information

Comment: Thank you, I really did not pay attention :D

Comment: if this resolved the issue, please answer your question as a solution.